# Best practices: Editing post title that is also the document id for the data on the page?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2, nuxtjs

I am building an app where users can write and edit blog posts. I have a `posts` subcollection under a `users` collection and each post's document id is the post's title which has been slugified so I can use it as pretty SEO links throughout the app (instead of like laksd723234adasdk38ql).

For example, a post URL would look like so:

`http://myblogdomain.com/users/XmdmZMZkzkRdpZ4oLX5u6MYA9B62/posts/test-again-and-here-and-there`

and the document id for that post is shown below in the firestore model screenshot:

[image]

**However, since I am also allowing users to edit the post title, I am unsure how to handle updating the post's document id. Can you update a document id? If so, is that even a good idea? Or, is there a better way to handle slugs and updating slugs? (Note: An example of this in action is stackoverflow.com: update a question's title and then when you refresh the page, the updated title is shown in the browser URL.)**

Here's a screenshot of example post data:

[image]

I am using Vue/Nuxt as the framework and so I have my page structure like this:

[image]

Comment: The purpose of a unique identifier is to allow a query (db or DOM related) to retrieve the element as fast as possible. I would only mix it with search engine indexing if and only if the id was immutable, as it would allow you to tell a search engine: this *human-readable-url* is an alias for this  *unique-not-so-pretty-url* and I'm serving the same content over them, so the search engine doesn't penalize you for serving the same content over multiple URLs. Also, since it asks for opinionated answers, your question is off-topic here. It's basically a SEO design issue, not a technical one.

Comment: Another problem your current urls might face: what happens when a post changes ownership? Will the old URL break? Maybe you should have `posts/immutable-unique-id` and then, in parallel, run a number of URL structures aliasing the main one `category/post-id`, `tag/post-id`, `user/post-id`, etc... The most important bit is to declare them as aliases of the main one, which remains unchanged.

Comment: THanks, @tao . Looks like I am going to need to search for some guides on this....dont know how to set up the aliases.

Comment: Look [no more](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization).